# Terminal tool window is missing in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

There is no terminal option present under Intellij-->View-->Tool Windows

Also there no shortcut option present at the bottom to open.

I use Intellij for JAVA coding.

My intelling version: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Community Edition)

Comment: I had the same issue. I just had to restart IntelliJ

Answer (score 2):

You should always have the Terminal tab in [Bottom left corner of the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sgwo.png)
also you can open it using the shortcut ⌥ (Option) + F12 on macOS

Edit: If It's still not visible press Command + Shift + A and type Terminal, It should appear like this.

[Cmd + Shift + A Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Grq.png)

Comment: Thanks Mehram, but I don't see these options in my mac Intellij 2022.1.3. I can see only Git, Run, TODO, Build, Problems, and Dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Mehram, but I don't see these options in my mac for Intellij version 2022.1.3. I can see only Git, Run, TODO, Build, Problems, and Dependencies at the bottom. I tried with ⌥ (Option) + F12 as well but no luck

Comment: I edited the answer, try this it should solve the problem.

Comment: If none of the above help try to delete the `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory while the IDE is closed.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Thank you so much. You are a genius, this worked for me but I am getting permission denied, could you please help me to resolve this as well?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of permission denied issue. Try to grant permissions for the mentioned file/folder from the macOS terminal and restart IDEA.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov yes it worked now perfectly now i ga e permissions to folder, thank you so much!